# LateX - If condition

Tags: if-statement, latex

I have some problem with the if condition in LateX. Is anyone can tell me why it never print "OK" ?

```
\def \scaleGraphX{0,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,100}

\foreach \x [count=\xi] in \scaleGraphX{
    \if \x = 0
        {OK} 
    \else 
        {PAS OK}
    \fi
}
```

Normally I should find at least 1 "OK"

Comment: Please create a minimal working example, so we can easily reproduce your situation. This should include the packages you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\ifnum` for numerical if tests:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\def\scaleGraphX{0,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,100}

\foreach \x [count=\xi] in \scaleGraphX{
    \ifnum\x=0
        {OK} 
    \else 
        {PAS OK}
    \fi
}



\end{document}
```